# Android Widget And Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I'm trying to create a widget for my application . I want it to be like this :
The user selects my widget among all widgets then a listview appears the user selects on of the items and the widget in that category (which is introduced in the application) will show up
 But when choosing the Widget "forceClose" happens . I attach my codes
Thanks for your help

```
public class WidgetConfig extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener { 

  AppWidgetManager awm;
  Context c;
  int awID;
  public String LS [] = {"C", "B", "A"}; 

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.id.listviewfirstshow);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.widget_config , LS));
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewfirstshow);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                           AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    else {
      finish ();
    }

    awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName() R.layout.widget);
    Intent in =  new Intent(c, WidgetLearn2Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, 0);
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(arg2, pi);
    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, rv);

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();

  }
}
```

and the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="learn.widget" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".WidgetLearn2Activity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />   
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".PointlessWidget" >
      <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff" />
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```